# Unity look input to get detail and change the scene

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I am new to unity..I want to ask that how to take action while looking on particular button or cube and then change the scene.

1. Look on object to see the hidden description of it.
2. Look on object and after 5 seconds loads the new scene.

**I have made the whole room scene with chairs and tables in  unity and I want to embed the above two points into that objects.**

Comment: This is an extremely general question that could cover a wide array of topics in unity.  What have you tried so far?  Is there a specific point you are stuck with?

Comment: I have an Google cardboard sample example code in which when clicked changes the position of cube in that I want to look for couple of seconds and then swich to new unity scene....

Comment: Have a lookt at Camera.ViewportPointToRay.  There is a code example there which will show you how to detect if you are looking at something.  Try playing with that for a bit, and if you need more help, edit your question to be more specific and include what code you have tried so far.  http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportPointToRay.html

Comment: @JamesHogle In this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MsVkT_nbMQ at time 0:50 sec how should i implement that thing ,i.e focus on icon and then switching to another scene.Please do refer any link or tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Raycasting and Tags.

For the 5 second delay you could register the time when you hit an object and save the tag for that object along with the time the raycast hit. And when 5 seconds passed, check if it's the same tag you're looking at.

Some helpful links:

- http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html
- http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html

Comment: could you please refer any youtube tutorial of any other descriptive tutorial